# I can choose one of these formats: OPUS 152 kbit/s vs AAC 128 kbit/s vs M4A 128 kbit/s. Which one is better?

Tags: music, format, aac-m4a

Here's more info of the same file but different formats, using `ffprobe` and `file` command of Linux:

#### OPUS (size 2.9 MB):

Command: `ffprobe -i "OPUS_AUDIO.opus"`
Output:

> Input #0, ogg, from 'OPUS_AUDIO.opus':
>    Duration: 00:02:39.87, start: 0.007500, bitrate: 143 kb/s
>      Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
>      Metadata:
>        encoder         : Lavf58.29.100

Command: `file "OPUS_AUDIO.opus"`
Output:

> OPUS_AUDIO.opus: Ogg data, Opus audio,

#### M4A (size 2.6 MB):

Command: `ffprobe -i "M4A_AUDIO.m4a"`
Output:

> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'M4A_AUDIO.m4a':
>    Metadata:
>      major_brand     : isom
>      minor_version   : 512
>      compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
>      title           : M4A_AUDIO
>      artist          : Artist
>      date            : 2022
>      encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
>    Duration: 00:02:39.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
>      Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
>      Metadata:
>      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.

Command: `file "M4A_AUDIO.m4a"`
Output:

> M4A_AUDIO.m4a: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]

#### AAC (size 2.6 MB):

Command: `ffprobe -i "AAC_AUDIO.aac"`
Output:

> [aac @ 0x564af8f33e40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
> Input #0, aac, from 'AAC_AUDIO.aac':
>    Duration: 00:02:24.10, bitrate: 144 kb/s
>      Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 144 kb/s

Command: `file "AAC_AUDIO.aac"`
Output:

> AAC_AUDIO.aac: MPEG ADTS, AAC, v4 LC, 44.1 kHz, stereo

Comment: The one nearest to source.

Answer (score 4):

This chart https://opus-codec.org/comparison/ shows that above 128 kb/s opus, aac and mp3 are very close in terms of quality.

So, as @Tetsujin mentions, the best one would be the one that is closest to the source